# Simple HTML/PHP Contact Form Not Working

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

I am trying to create simple HTML/PHP Contact form, But this is not working correctly. Pl check this below given code that's I'm actually trying.

My simple form process

HTML form,

```
<form action="send_mail.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" name="myform" >

        <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="email">
        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="FormMail E-Mail">`
        <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
        <tr>
        <td align="left">Nome:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">Mensagem</td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td><textarea style="resize:none;" cols="44" rows="8" name="message" id="message"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="left">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Aceder"><input type="reset" value="Recompor">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="thankyou.html"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$to = "xyz@abc.com";
$subject = "Email from Xyz company";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
else
{
echo "Failure!";
}
?>
```

I am using this code, plz suggest me if there is any error in my code and any changes required..

Thank you.

Comment: Well what is the error you're receiving if any? "this is not working correctly" What's not working correctly? How? Some more information please? What's the expected output and what is the actual output?

Comment: You have `"` missing in line `$subject = "Email from Xyz company;`

Answer (score 2):

**quotation marks end on subject?**

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $to = "xyz@abc.com";
    $subject = "Email from Xyz company; // quotation marks end?
    $name_field = $_POST['name'];
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Failure!";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You may want to add a title to this? May be very handy.

Comment: are you trying in localhost? coz doesnt work mail function on localhost if there isnt a smtp.

Comment: I am trying in live website. mail isn't receiving in given address. not even showing any error.

Comment: did you look at the spam box?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP Code on the line 4 the quotation marks are missing at the end of the line before `;`.
Correct line 4:

```
$subject = "Email from Xyz company";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change above PHP code to this;

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$to = "xyz@abc.com";
$subject = "Email from Xyz company";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
else
{
echo "Failure!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$to = "xyz@abc.com";
$subject = "Email from Xyz company";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8' . "\r\n";

 if( !mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) )
 {
   echo "Failure!";
 }
}
?>
```